# How to get ArrayList type and create an ArrayList based off that?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this method to read a **txt** file. First it converts the **.txt** file to an `Object`, and then checks if it is an `ArrayList`. If it is I want to create an `ArrayList` of whatever type obj is.

```
    public static readFile(String fileName) {
        Object obj = null;
        
        try {
            obj = deserialize(fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }

        ArrayList<?> list;

        if (obj instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
            list = (ArrayList<?>) obj;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I know all elements of the `ArrayList` will be of the same type in my scenario so I was thinking about using `list.get(0).getClass()`. I tried doing `ArrayList<(list.get(0).getClass()>` but it doesn't work so I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Converting it to `ArrayList<?>` is no different from converting it to `ArrayList` of whatever type the first object happens to be. When a Java program is running, all the objects of generic type lose their type parameters.  The distinction between `ArrayList<Foo>` and `ArrayList<Bar>` only exists at compile time.

Comment: What is your concrete problem with this code snippet? (except the method declaration won't compile for missing return type) You can declare method to return `List<T>` where `T` is type of "all elements of the ArrayList" you know they are "of the same type".

Comment: Your method declaration doesn't have a return type.  What do actually want the (compile time) return type to be?  That is the nub of this problem!  (The runtime type of all `ArrayList` objects is the same ... irrespective of what is in the lists.)

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking about using list.get(0).getClass() I tried doing ArrayList<(list.get(0).getClass()>

Generics is a **compile time** mechanism. Its purpose is to allow the compiler to verify that manipulations in your code are type-safe.

And during the compilation `ArrayList<Something>` turn into `ArrayList<Object>`, this process is called [*generic type erasure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html).

You can't provide a generic type through a method call, like `list.get(0).getClass()`.

If you want to benefit from generics, then you need to provide the Generic type explicitly, and can't be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that!

Think about that, if you can do that, it same to this:

`ArrayList<Integer> instanceof ArrayList<?>`
or
`ArrayList<Integer> instanceof ArrayList<Number>`

`Integer` is a `Number`, that is ok, but as generics is **invariance**, `ArrayList<Integer>` is not a `ArrayList<Number>`. This contradicts the above.